# AEM 6.3 404 errors with font files

Tags: aem, aem-6

I'm running sassLib/bourbon to building out my CSS. It builds fine, and adds the main.css file to my frontend folder in the clientlib-site folder. I also have a fonts folder in there too, but can't get the path set correctly. I'm getting 404 errors for each of my font files.

here's my scss code snippet:

```css
/* base fonts */
$fontPath: '../../frontend/fonts/';
// Helvectica Neauve Medium
@include font-face('Helvetica Neavue Medium', '#{$fontPath}HelveticaNeueLTW02-65Medium');
// Helvetica Neavue Light
@include font-face('Helvetica Neavue Light', '#{$fontPath}HelveticaNeueW02-45Light');
```

My clientLibs is like this

/apps//clientlibs/clientlib-site/frontend

If there is more information needed, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share the actual font path in the JCR?

Comment: I assume this is what you're asking for: '\jcr_root\apps\bbcom-aem-project\clientlibs\clientlib-site\frontend'

Comment: i'm asking to see the full path to the font file in JCR. Clientlib/path/fonts/<what>?  Also, please post the 404 you get in browser to (with the url)

Comment: @MarkHandy can you just have an absolute path for your fonts instead?

Comment: The AEM dev figured it out, but I haven't had a chance to look at his solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can define font family by "Day Commons GFX Font Helper"

Please follow this link

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/platform/adding-fonts.html

For using:

```
p {
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
}
```

Comment: I had tried this, but as I wasn't rendering graphics, it wasn't helping.